# How to have access to files via shell commands in mac os x application?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, shell, cocoa

Im new to developing mac applications. (but I have work a lot for ios)

For start I want to have a window on which there is a button. When user click on the button, it should trigger an action that will run some shell commands inside the folder that the user dragged & dropped inside the app before.

**For example** 
User will drag and drop some folder inside my app and the app should create gemfile inside this folder.

Here is my current version where I run the shell and the first command is `cd <pathToFolder>` but the output is `/usr/bin/cd: line 4: cd: file:///Users/klemen/Downloads/ABCAcura/: No such file or directory`

Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func handleCreateGemfileButton(_ sender: NSButton) {

  let pipe = Pipe()
  let process = Process()
  process.launchPath = "/bin/bash"
  process.arguments = ["cd", projectURL.absoluteString]
  process.standardOutput = pipe
  let file = pipe.fileHandleForReading
  process.launch()

  if let result = NSString(data: file.readDataToEndOfFile(), encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) {
    print(result as String)
  }
  else {
    print("error")
  }
}
```

Is there some restrictions. How is it possible to request from user that my app will have access to some of his files?

Comment: Is the `<pathToFolder>` `~/Downloads/ABCAcura/` or is it an argument?

Comment: file:///Users/klemen/Downloads/ABCAcura/   OK, I see, this is probably the problem the prefix is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `~/Downloads/ABCAcura` instead of `file:///...`, `file:///` is a protocol (URL) not a path to file.